# Why does body2 overrides body font size in material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

When specifying body2 styles it overrides body font size. Shouldn't it be a variant of **Typography** component?

[image]

Comment: That is part of the functionality of CssBaseline: https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#typography.

Comment: Yes I know, but isn't it confusing? Because when I theme I assume the styles for body (base font setting for the entire HTML doc) should be overridden by the properties defined for 'typography' and anything defined under 'body1' & 'body2' should be used just as variants.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended use is for the `fontSize` that is directly under `typography`, but it isn't usable for styling the body because only the variants have the full properties necessary (e.g. lineHeight, fontWeight, and letterSpacing are only defined within the variants).

Comment: Yup, I agree. Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: Just to contribute on @RyanCogswell comment - the link now leads to MUI CssBaseline component documentation, where body1 overrides the page body element styles. For older version, see https://v4.mui.com/components/css-baseline/#typography - here body2 overrides body styles